# How to use categorial focal loss for one hot encoding with keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am working on epilepsy seizure prediction. I have imbalanced dataset I want to make it balanced by using focal loss. I have 2 classes one-hot encoding vector. I found the below focal loss code but I don't know how I can get `y_pred` to be used in focal loss code before `model.fit_generator` .

`y_pred` is the output of the model. So how I can use it in the focal loss code before fitting my model??

**focal loss code:**

```
def categorical_focal_loss(gamma=2.0, alpha=0.25):
    """
    Implementation of Focal Loss from the paper in multiclass classification
    Formula:
        loss = -alpha*((1-p)^gamma)*log(p)
    Parameters:
        alpha -- the same as wighting factor in balanced cross entropy
        gamma -- focusing parameter for modulating factor (1-p)
    Default value:
        gamma -- 2.0 as mentioned in the paper
        alpha -- 0.25 as mentioned in the paper
    """
    def focal_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        # Define epsilon so that the backpropagation will not result in NaN
        # for 0 divisor case
        epsilon = K.epsilon()
        # Add the epsilon to prediction value
        #y_pred = y_pred + epsilon
        # Clip the prediction value
        y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, epsilon, 1.0-epsilon)
        # Calculate cross entropy
        cross_entropy = -y_true*K.log(y_pred)
        # Calculate weight that consists of  modulating factor and weighting factor
        weight = alpha * y_true * K.pow((1-y_pred), gamma)
        # Calculate focal loss
        loss = weight * cross_entropy
        # Sum the losses in mini_batch
        loss = K.sum(loss, axis=1)
        return loss
    
    return focal_loss
```

**My code:**

```
history=model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, train_data, start=0,end=100)
validation_data=generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, test_data, start=0,end=100)
steps_per_epoch=int((len(train_data)/2)), 
                                validation_steps=int((len(test_data)/2)),
                                verbose=2,epochs=65, max_queue_size=2, shuffle=True)
preictPrediction=model.predict_generator(generate_arrays_for_predict(indexPat, filesPath_data), max_queue_size=4, steps=len(filesPath_data))
y_pred1=np.argmax(preictPrediction,axis=1)
y_pred=list(y_pred1)
```

Comment: Do you mean how to compile the model by using focal loss?

Comment: @Frightera the code of focal loss should be before ‘model.fit_generator’ and ‘y_pred’ is the output of the model. So how I will use ‘y_pred’ in the focal loss code ?

Comment: I think you are confused, you don't need y_pred before calling fit_generator, or I am not understanding the question correctly (consider that other people do not understand either)

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I think I need it in `def focal_loss(y_true, y_pred):` function in the focal loss code. Is that correct ?? , sorry I am using focal loss for the first time may be I am confused.

Comment: This is not specific to focal loss, all keras loss functions take y_true and y_pred, you do not need to worry where those parameters are coming from, they are fed by keras automatically.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I understand. Thank you so much for your help I really appreciate that.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Perhaps you should post an answer so the question is no longer considered unanswered by the system (apparently the question gets quite a high vote-count)

Comment: @user202729 For that the question needs to be clear, for me it is still unclear, seems to just be a misconception.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I got this error when I run the code `TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int64 of argument 'x'.` , any help in how to solve this error would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment section for the benefit of the community.

> This is not specific to `focal loss`, all keras loss functions take
> `y_true` and `y_pred`, you do not need to worry where those parameters are
> coming from, they are fed by `keras` automatically.